# Why Dropdown Selected value pass as a null value to the controller in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown created in Html as like this.

```
<label for="filter">Type:</label> 
  <select class="filter"
    id="secquneceDropdownId">
      <option value="" selected>All</option>
      <option value="INSEQUENCE">In Sequence</option>
      <option value="OUTSEQUENCE">Out Sequence</option>
      <option value="RECIPES">Sequence Mapping</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried to send selected value in jQuery as same as the Ajax JSON format. but I always get the null value in the backend.

Both ways are here,

Using jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#secquneceDropdownId").change(function () {
        var dropdownSelected = $(this).val();
       console.log('dropdownSelected value is' + dropdownSelected); 


      $.post("/IdeaOfThings/listSequences", {
            isDropdownSelected : dropdownSelected

        },

        function(data, status) {
        });
});
});
```

In Ajax format:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#secquneceDropdownId").change(function () {
            var dropdownSelected = $(this).val();
           console.log('dropdownSelected value is' + dropdownSelected); 
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/IdeaOfThings//listSequences', 
                data: {isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected},
                dataType: "json",

            success: function(data){
                if(data.success==true){
                    alert('success');
                }else if(data.success==false){
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            }
            }); 
});
});
```

Why I`m getting null value as always.?

Comment: did you set the value of dropdownSelected anywhere ?

e.g. 
var dropdownSelected  = $('#secquneceDropdownId').val()

Comment: In Spring boot i did these two in the controller.   String isDropdownSelected = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("isDropdownSelected"));  request.setAttribute("seqList", seqDelegate.dropDownSelection(isDropdownSelected, userName));

Comment: @irvins Yeah it is in the front end code segment. var dropdownSelected = $(this).val();  . actually console log will print the selected value as well.

Comment: Check i ll update my question

Comment: @irvins I updated my question

Comment: try adding 
contentType: 'application/json'
to ajax request settings.

and/or 
data: JSON.stringify({isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected})

Comment: @irvins i tried that too . but console error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Comment: Test your rest api with postman before implementing .

Comment: As i`m a full stack developer i have to deal with both front end and the back end. i debug the program so backend getting null value if i select different options though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing

```
data: {isDropdownSelected: dropdownSelected}
```

to

```
data: {'isDropdownSelected': dropdownSelected}
```

Comment: I tried this too but in the console http://localhost:8080/IdeaOfThings/listSequences 405 () get prints

Comment: Could it be that you are required to send some kind of token with your post request to make it a valid request? Like csrf token in request header or something (for example in laravel)

Comment: No . this is for conditions to retrieve data from the database.